# I can't display my app on facebook

Tags: php, facebook

I'm having a little problem with the whole Facebook app development.
I created an facebook application and gave it an IP for my server.
I set my .php script file on the server and set the secret key and appId.
When I click on the app on my Facebook account to reach it, I get an "Uploading (0%)" text on the bottom of the browser and eventually I get a message:
"This webpage is not available".
When I used the "Heroku" hosting service, I got an app.

I think the problem is the communication between Facebook and my server but I don't know what.

I tried almost everything.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you set the canvas urls correctly? Does the url you mention in canvas url work fine from outside Facebook?

Comment: I think I set it correctly.
Here's how I set the URL's:
[1]: http://myIP/myFolder/
[2]: https://myIP/myFolder/
The above URL's are prefixed with http:// and https:// respectevly

I can reach that URL from outside Facebook i.e. if I type that URL into the address bar of the browser, I'm reaching it and get the response.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I used a forward slash at the end of the URL's

Answer (score 0):

If you issue a request to your application from the linter tool?

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

If you run your own application url through there and don't see any activity then Facebook just cant access your server and you need to do some work with your firewall.

Comment: I tried that tool.
I got:

Response Code: 200
Fetched URL: http://ip/fbApp/
Canonical URL: http://ip/fbApp/
Can't Download: Could not retrieve data from URL.
I set the firewall off but nothing changed.
What other thing my be causing it?

Comment: Your own router is most likely blocking the traffic. Is this application running on your local machine? I cant reach the url for example from my machine here so Facebook won't be able to get there unless you have some sort of specific rules setup for incoming FB User Agents.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.
The machine has no router and no other restriction that I know.
I used $facebook->getSession() which I saw that is deprecated.

Comment: I'm also getting an error about a og:url missing:
Missing Required Property: The 'og:url' property is required, but not present.
I don't have a lot of experience with it so I don't know if it's connected with it. The code that I use for the app was copied from here: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php

Comment: Ok. So I reached the best result so far.
I used the tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2F109.226.8.202%2FfbApp%2F
and I got 200 response code and no errors.
but when I try to enter the url of the app in facebook I get "Uploading...(0%)". Why am I still getting this message???

Comment: OK. I solved the problem, although I don't really understand why the thing that I did, solved it.
I created a web site with https binding. I created a certificate on the IIS and the than I could see my application. Now that I think about it, I don't think that creating a certificate really matters...